# Reading JSON data for my select query in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

I am building a testcafe web automation project with a data-driven framework. I am using NPM/node.jS/ with Visual Studio Code. I have a JSON File and a SQL query, I want to point the where clause of the SQL query to the JSON data. This is very new to me, any suggestions are welcome.

I saw that there is an NPM JSON-SQL Node.JS library, but I have not used it, any example will help me.

Json file:

```
[
{
 venid='ABC'
 status='Open'
},
{
 venid='IGH'
 status='Closed'
},
```

SQL query:

```
// running the query and query will take data from the json file
Select * 
From table 
Where VendorId = <jsondata> 
  and Inventorystatus = <jsonData>
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to parse a `JSON` data using SQL Server, you should use [JSON capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), which are introduced in SQL Server 2016. Most of the scripting languages have enough capabilities to wotk with `JSON` format, so you should pass `JSON` data directly to SQL Server.

Next is a basic example, which you may use as a starting point (note, that your `JSON` is not valid):

Table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   VendorId nvarchar(3),
   InventoryStatus nvarchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (VendorId, InventoryStatus)
VALUES
   (N'ABC', N'Open'),
   (N'ABC', N'Closed'),
   (N'IGH', N'Open'),
   (N'IGH', N'Closed')
```

T-SQL:

```
-- Valid JSON
-- [{"venid":"ABC", "status":"Open"}, {"venid":"IGH", "status":"Closed"}]
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

-- Read JSON from file. Try to send JSON data directly to SQL Server.
-- Additional permissions are needed to execute next statement.
--SELECT @json = BulkColumn
--FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '<Path>\JsonData.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

-- Read JSON from variable
SELECT @json = N'[{"venid":"ABC", "status":"Open"}, {"venid":"IGH", "status":"Closed"}]'

-- Use JSON data in a statement
SELECT d.*
FROM #Data d
JOIN OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    VendorId nvarchar(3) '$.venid',
    InventoryStatus nvarchar(10) '$.status'
) j ON (d.VendorId = j.VendorId) AND (d.InventoryStatus = j.InventoryStatus)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------
VendorId    InventoryStatus
---------------------------
ABC         Open
IGH         Closed
```